# How to force enable Google Chrome Dark Mode for web content?

Tags: google-chrome, dark-mode

I am trying to enable the new experimental dark mode feature in Chrome for web content. I tried looking into my Chrome settings but I found no straightforward way of doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable Forced Dark Mode in Chrome 78 and later, follow these steps:

1. Enter the following address in your URL bar: `chrome://flags/#enable-force-dark`
2. This will bring up a hidden Chrome settings menu and the Force Dark Mode option.
3. Go the drop-down menu next to Force Dark Mode and select Enabled.
4. At the bottom, hit the Relaunch button to restart your browser.

Source: [How to force Google Chrome to show any website in dark mode](https://www.pocket-lint.com/apps/news/google/149866-how-to-enable-dark-mode-for-google-chrome)